Flutter Build For IOS error on VMWare MacOS , not found profiles "...." issue,?
I have an error in photo, I using VMware MacOS 13, Xcode V12.5.
I have personal apple id account but ı want build for my company, personal account and company name different.
and so flutter giving that error.
please help me.
I tried change account name but I can't, how can I fix?

Please add some more information. like steps you perform.

added errror's image

Hi please enable automatic signin, using Project -> Target -> Signing and capabilities, checkmark Automatic manage signing

It is already checked, but it gives a warning at the bottom, saying there is no device, I think it might be giving this error because I am using a virtual Mac and I do not have any iPhone or Mac original device?

"No profiles for 'com.companyname.appname' were found
Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.companyname.appname'."   giving this error

I didn't create the apple developer account and of course I didn't pay.
Could the problem be caused by this?

If you do not have device, still you can run  app on simulator. In virtual mac also you can run the app. Apple id is enough for running app on simulator. You just need to check you are logged in XCode -> Preferences -> Account. And need to select your team name in Signning and capabilities.
